# gdal_calc.py where is the output file, when you're using --outfile==

Tags: python, gdal

I have two raster files and I calculated them. Now I need to get that output file. When I used gdal_calc.py

Where is that output file stored in my pc?

Comment: What exactly was your command line?

Comment: If you run it out of the osgeo4w shell in windows it would be in the root folder like C:\OSGeo4W

Answer (score 4):

If you give only the file name the result will be saved into to the same directory where you run the command.

```
gdal_calc -A test.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="(A)"
```

If you include a path, the result will be saved where you ask to save it

```
gdal_calc -A test.tif --outfile=c:/test/result.tif --calc="(A)"
```

If you observe something else, please add the gdal_calc command that you used.